# React Query String not being displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-router, query-string

I am using query-string to pass some parameters and render the below component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Show extends Component {

  constructor(props,context) {
        super(props,context);
        this.state = {
          name: ''
        };
        console.log(this);

    }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Hi {this.props.match.params.name} </h4>
        <p></p>
        {this.props.match.params.name ? <b>ID: {this.props.match.params.name}</b> : }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Show;
```

The route is like below :

```
    <Route path='/show/:name?' component={Show} />
```

But this always  results in undefined name and I see only Hi not the name .I use the below versions .

```
"react-dom": "^16.13.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"query-string": "^6.11.1"
```

Not sure where I am making a mistake .Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Copy/pasted your code; I'm unable to repro. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-morning-xezlf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&initialpath=%2Fshow%2Ftest&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark

Comment: you can see that when I query https://xezlf.csb.app/show?name=james the name james doesn't show in the page like Hi james

Comment: I see, you've conflated match parameters with query parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query path query parameters from the [`location`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) prop.

```
props.location.search
```

If route path is `"/show/:name"`, the `match` prop will have the path parameter `name`, i.e. `props.match.params.name`, and any URL query parameters will simply be appended to the URL and can be found on the `location` prop.

Usage:

```
class Show extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      name: ""
    };
    console.log(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Math Param {this.props.match.params.name} </h4>
        <h3>Query {this.props.location.search} </h3>
        <p />
        {this.props.match.params.name && (
          <b>ID: {this.props.match.params.name}</b>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit vigilant-morning-xezlf]

Answer (score 0):

Query string is used with a longer URL with something after the "?". If i type in `localhost:3000/show/bob?` the props.location object would have the pathname as `/show/bob`, so you don't really need it for this specific route.

I reproduced your code locally and wasn't getting 'undefined' for name, I was getting the expected output. Make sure that your App component routes are surrounded by a `<Router>` tag like this:

```
<Router>
     <Route path='/show/:name?' component={Show} />
</Router>
```

Also the if/else conditional in your show component needs something after the else operator. Either use && or add `null` after it.

If you're interested in hooks check out the useParams() hook [here](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/#useparams). It provides url parameters for you.